# coordinates returned are not correct

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers3 with OSM as a background map. I'm retrieving coordinates when clicking on the map. However, for some reason I do not understand, the coordinates returned differ from what they should be. 
The crs is EPSG:3857 and the coordinates returned are for example:

> `[149320862354.13303, 7149613.877682245]`

But they rather should look like this:

> `[1347655.049747, 7147342.608955]`

I do not know why they are returned like this. I did not change anything in my code or configuration.

```
 map.on('singleclick', function (e) {
  var coordinates = map.getEventCoordinate(e.originalEvent);
   console.log(coordinates);
}
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Edit:

I've logged the map object to console:

```
projection_: ol.proj.EPSG3857_
revision_: 0
values_: Object
center: Array[2]
0: 149320863424.25146
1: 7177589.830034621
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
resolution: 152.8740565703525
rotation: 0
```

As you can see the coordinates of the center (especially center[0]) are wrong. I guess this issue may be caused by creating the map.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
   gnMap.getLayersFromConfig() //MapQuest, OSM, Bing                 
  ],
  renderer: 'canvas',
  view: new ol.View({
   center: [0, 0],
   projection: 'EPSG:3857',
   zoom: 2
  })
});
```

But I can't figure out why those are either created or returned wrong.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a full example (e.g. on JSFiddle)?

Comment: Hello @tsauerwein and thanks for you reply. For some reason I can't explain, the coordinates (as well as the map) returned are correct now. Anyway: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x36uz94u/).

Comment: You could also simplify your code. The event has a `coordinate` property that you can use directly (`e.coordinate`).